# python using concurrent futures to read file asynchronously method guidance

Tags: python, concurrency

I want to add `concurrency.futures` module asynchronous I/O reading to my script. I want file to be read one time, then the result to be worked on.
As logic of module does not align with it I created two different functions which separately reads two separate time the file, as pandas dataframe and then gives me the result.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys,os, time,re
import concurrent.futures

start=(time.perf_counter())
def getting_file_path(fileName):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        path_actual = os.getcwd()
        path_main_folder = path_actual[:-4]
        path_result = path_main_folder + fileName
        print('frozen path',os.path.normpath(path_result))
        return path_result
    else:
        return fileName


def read_keys_dropdown():
    global lst_dropdown_keys
    file_to_read = pd.read_json(getting_file_path('./ConfigurationFile/configFile.csv'))
    lst_dropdown_keys=list(file_to_read.to_dict().keys())
    lst_dropdown_keys.pop(0)
    lst_dropdown_keys.pop(-1)
    return lst_dropdown_keys


def read_url():
    pattern = re.compile(r"^(?:/.|[^//])*/((?:\\.|[^/\\])*)/")
    file_to_read=pd.read_json(getting_file_path('./ConfigurationFile/configFile.csv'))
    result = (re.match(pattern, file_to_read.values[0][0]))
    return pattern.match(file_to_read.values[0][0]).group(1)


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    res_1=executor.submit(read_keys_dropdown)
    res_2=executor.submit(read_url)
    finish=(time.perf_counter())
    print(res_1.result(),res_2.result(),finish-start,sep=';')
```

Before, I was doing it differently. I was reading `file_to_read = pd.read_json(getting_file_path('./ConfigurationFile/configFile.csv'))` in global scope then using that variable name in both functions.
I tried to do something like reading data, and then working on result it gave me `Futures` object has no `attribute` to_dict, nor values[0]...so, if I need to fasten my script and concurrency or threading modules are better choice for I/O reading files, then how else I can use them in my script?

Comment: You're making this unnecessarily complicated for no apparent gain in performance. Better to write a class that does a "lazy" load of the configuration file

Comment: the problem is in that, I am new also for `oop` mind. So, if I put `getting_file_path()` function in new class, and `file_to_read` variable in Class, then then...if i call class one time it will already be read file?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. That was on my mind, to have a good suggestion where to use classes

Comment: Can you look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75823739/python-class-method-invocation-missing-1-required-positional-argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could use a class with "lazy" loading.

The logic in the *path()* and *read_keys_dropdown()* functions is taken from the original question and is very likely not going to achieve the desired objective.

This is obviously untested and there are outstanding questions such as why *read_json()* is being used for a CSV file.

```
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
import re

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, filename='./ConfigurationFile/configFile.csv'):
        self._filename = filename
        self._path = None
        self._df = None
        self._pattern = None

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self._filename

    @property
    def path(self):
        if self._path is None:
            if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
                # the following code looks highly dubious
                path_actual = os.getcwd()
                path_main_folder = path_actual[:-4]
                self._path = path_main_folder + self.filename
                print('frozen path', os.path.normpath(self._path))
            else:
                self._path = self.filename
        return self._path

    @property
    def df(self):
        if self._df is None:
            self._df = pd.read_json(self.path)
        return self._df

    @property
    def pattern(self):
        if self._pattern is None:
            self._pattern = re.compile(r"^(?:/.|[^//])*/((?:\\.|[^/\\])*)/")
        return self._pattern

    def read_keys_dropdown(self):
        # the following code looks highly dubious
        lst_dropdown_keys = list(self.df.to_dict().keys())
        lst_dropdown_keys.pop(0)
        lst_dropdown_keys.pop(-1)
        return lst_dropdown_keys

    def read_url(self):
        if m := self.pattern.match(self.df.values[0][0]):
            return m.group(1)


clazz = MyClass()

print(clazz.read_keys_dropdown())
print(clazz.read_url())
```

Comment: I tried, works perfect! Data is saved csv but format is in json. Thanks!