# python class method invocation missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, class

I created class method to ease file reading. But the end result gives me the following error message:

```
TypeError: Read_file.file_reading_through_class() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fileName'
```

My code is below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sys,os, time,re
   
class Read_file():
    def file_reading_through_class(self,fileName):
        if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            path_actual = os.getcwd()
            path_main_folder = path_actual[:-4]
            path_result = path_main_folder + fileName
            print('frozen path', os.path.normpath(path_result))
            file_to_read = pd.read_json(path_result)
            return file_to_read
        else:
            file_to_read = pd.read_json(fileName)
            return file_to_read
   
file_read=Read_file.file_reading_through_class('./ConfigurationFile/configFile.csv')
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to instantiate the class first.
`self` refers to the instance of the class.

```
rf = Read_file()
file_read = rf.file_reading_through_class('./ConfigurationFile/configFile.csv')
```

Or you can mark your function as a static method, and you can use your function the way you are using it.

```
@staticmethod
def file_reading_through_class(fileName):
```

Answer (score 2):

You calling the method as if it was a static method.

The following code will work:

```
import sys, os, time, re    
import pandas as pd



class Read_file():
    def file_reading_through_class(self,fileName):
        if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            path_actual = os.getcwd()
            path_main_folder = path_actual[:-4]
            path_result = path_main_folder + fileName
            print('frozen path', os.path.normpath(path_result))
            file_to_read = pd.read_json(path_result)
            return file_to_read
        else:
            file_to_read = pd.read_json(fileName)
            return file_to_read

reader = Read_file()
file_read = reader.file_reading_through_class('./ConfigurationFile/configFile.csv')
```

Or if you really want it to be a static method then you can use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys, os, time, re


class Read_file():
    @staticmethod
    def file_reading_through_class(fileName):
        if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            path_actual = os.getcwd()
            path_main_folder = path_actual[:-4]
            path_result = path_main_folder + fileName
            print('frozen path', os.path.normpath(path_result))
            file_to_read = pd.read_json(path_result)
            return file_to_read
        else:
            file_to_read = pd.read_json(fileName)
            return file_to_read

file_read=Read_file.file_reading_through_class('./ConfigurationFile/configFile.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

### Attribute references

In the [link proposed by the comment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) of  @chepner it is explained a different way to access to an attribute of a class:

> MyClass.i and MyClass.f are valid attribute references, returning an integer and a function object, respectively.

The documentation calls this operation supported by a Class *Attribute references* while calls the access by an instance *Class instantiation*.

Adapting the *Attribute references* to your code we obtain:

```
file_read=Read_file.file_reading_through_class(Read_file,'./ConfigurationFile/configFile.csv')
```

Where by `Read_file.file_reading_through_class` we obtain a reference to the attribute `file_reading_through_class` that is a function object.
Furthermore the previous instruction executes the function passing to it 2 parameters:

- `Read_file` for argument `self` (*this is the the missing argument that you cite in the title of your question*)
- `'./ConfigurationFile/configFile.csv'` for argument `fileName`.

I can divide the previous instruction in two instructions fully equivalent:

```
func_reference = Read_file.file_reading_through_class
file_read = func_reference(Read_file, './ConfigurationFile/configFile.csv')
```

where I have highlighted the reference to the attribute `file_reading_through_class`.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74448113/testing-python-methods-call-sequence-in-a-multithreaded-context/74472438#74472438) contains an example where the use of *Class Attribute references* is useful.